# Как получить информацию о подключенном устройстве?

Tags: linux, windows, qt, winapi, usb

Я пишу на С++, использую Qt под Windows. Мне надо получить: название модели, изготовителя, серийный номер устройства(видео камеры, фото , квадрокоптера , флешки или SD Card) и путь до устройства. Желательно кроссплатформенное решение.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ответ [SetupDiGetDeviceProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438366/setupdigetdeviceproperty-usage-example). Но тут не кроссплатформенное решение , к тому же я не совсем понимаю как получить путь до устройства.
Читал о библиотеки [libusb](https://libusb.info/). Но тут не выводятся название модели, изготовителя, серийный номер устройства. То что выводиться :

```
Dev (bus 2, device 0): 8086 - 1E31
Dev (bus 1, device 4): 04A9 - 1795
Dev (bus 1, device 3): A4Tech - USB Mouse
Dev (bus 3, device 0): 8086 - 1E26
Dev (bus 1, device 1): 8087 - 0024
Dev (bus 1, device 0): 8086 - 1E2D
Dev (bus 1, device 2): 0BDA - 0151
Dev (bus 1, device 6): Logitech Inc. - Logitech USB Headset H340
Dev (bus 3, device 2): 8087 - 0024
Dev (bus 3, device 3): Logitech - USB Keyboard
Dev (bus 3, device 1): 04A9 - 3206
```

Хотя была вставлена флешка и подключена камера.
Есть изящное решение этой задачи. Если кто сталкивался с такой задачей поделитесь кодом пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4):

К сожалению, используя библиотеку libusb под Windows нельзя вытянуть всю эту информацию без установки специального драйвера WinUSB. Можно только получить VID и PID (шестнадцатеричные значения типа 8086 - 1E31 в вашем примере), и по ним найти производителя и устройство в таблице известных идентификаторов, например [здесь](http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids).

Производителя и серийный номер можно получить, используя Setup API и *IOCTL_USB_GET_DESCRIPTOR_FROM_NODE_CONNECTION*. Букву диска тоже можно получить только средствами Setup API, это несколько сложнее. Для этого нужно вначале построить таблицу номеров дисков для всех используемых букв дисков с помощью *IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER*; затем открыть интересующее устройство (запоминающее устройство, которое является дочерним для USB-устройства), найти его номер тем же IOCTL, сравнить его со значениями из таблицы и таким образом определить букву. Как-то так:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

#include <windows.h>
#include <Setupapi.h>
#include <winusb.h>
#undef LowSpeed
#include <Usbioctl.h>
#include <Devpkey.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"Setupapi.lib")

void ErrorMes(LPCTSTR lpszFunction) 
{ 
    // Retrieve the system error message for the last-error code

    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError(); 

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL );

    // Display the error message 

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, 
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf) + lstrlen(lpszFunction) + 40) * sizeof(TCHAR)); 
    wprintf(L"%s failed with error %d: %s", 
        lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf);     

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
}

//Поиск номера диска для USB-устройства
BOOL FindDiskNumber(LPCWSTR match, STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER* lpret){

    BOOL retval = FALSE;
    DEVPROPTYPE dpt=0;
    wchar_t buffer[1024]=L"";
    TCHAR id_upper[1024]=L"";
    DWORD RequiredSize = 0;
    SP_DEVINFO_DATA devinfo = { 0 };
    SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA deviceInterface = { 0 };
    PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA deviceInterfaceDetail = NULL;
    BOOL res;  

    HDEVINFO deviceInfoHandle = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK, 0, 0, DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE);

    if (deviceInfoHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        int deviceIndex = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            ZeroMemory(&deviceInterface,sizeof(deviceInterface));
            deviceInterface.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA);

            //получение всех дисков
            if (SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(deviceInfoHandle, 0, &GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK, deviceIndex, &deviceInterface))
            {
                DWORD cbRequired = 0;

                SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(deviceInfoHandle, &deviceInterface, 0, 0, &cbRequired, 0);
                if (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER == GetLastError())
                {
                    deviceInterfaceDetail =  (PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA)(new char[cbRequired]);
                    memset(deviceInterfaceDetail, 0, cbRequired);
                    deviceInterfaceDetail->cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA);

                    if (!SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(deviceInfoHandle, &deviceInterface, 
                        deviceInterfaceDetail, cbRequired, &cbRequired, 0))
                    {
                        goto Next;
                    }

                    // Initialize the structure before using it.
                    memset(deviceInterfaceDetail, 0, cbRequired);
                    deviceInterfaceDetail->cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA);

                    // Call the API a second time to retrieve the actual
                    // device path string.
                    BOOL status = SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(
                        deviceInfoHandle,  // Handle to device information set
                        &deviceInterface,     // Pointer to current node in devinfo set
                        deviceInterfaceDetail,   // Pointer to buffer to receive device path
                        cbRequired,   // Length of user-allocated buffer
                        &cbRequired,  // Pointer to arg to receive required buffer length
                        NULL);        // Not interested in additional data


                    //получение информации о устройстве 
                    ZeroMemory(&devinfo,sizeof(devinfo));
                    devinfo.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA);
                    BOOL success = SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(deviceInfoHandle, deviceIndex, &devinfo);
                    if(success==FALSE){ErrorMes(L"SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo"); goto Next;}

                    res=SetupDiGetDeviceProperty(deviceInfoHandle,&devinfo,
                     &DEVPKEY_Device_Parent,&dpt,(PBYTE)buffer,1000,NULL,0);
                    if(res==FALSE){ErrorMes(L"SetupDiGetDeviceProperty");goto Next;}

                    int len = wcslen(buffer);
                    for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
                        id_upper[i]=toupper(buffer[i]);//преобразование в заглавные буквы
                    }                   

                    if(wcsstr(id_upper,match)!=NULL){ //если ID родительского устройства содержит нужную строку

                        /*Открываем устройство для отправки IOCTL*/                 
                        HANDLE handle = CreateFile(deviceInterfaceDetail->DevicePath, 0, 
                        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 
                        0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

                        if(handle==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {  
                            ErrorMes(L"CreateFile");goto Next;
                        }

                        STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER sdn = {0};
                        DWORD nbytes = 0;

                        //получение номера диска
                        res = DeviceIoControl(handle,                // handle to device
                            IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER, // dwIoControlCode
                            NULL,                            // lpInBuffer
                            0,                               // nInBufferSize
                            (LPVOID) &sdn,           // output buffer
                            (DWORD) sizeof(sdn),         // size of output buffer
                            (LPDWORD) &nbytes,       // number of bytes returned
                            NULL      // OVERLAPPED structure
                        );
                        CloseHandle(handle);

                        if(res != FALSE){
                            //устройство найдено
                            memcpy(lpret,&sdn,sizeof(sdn));
                            retval = TRUE;
                        }
                        else ErrorMes(L"DeviceIoControl");

                   }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }

            Next:
            if(deviceInterfaceDetail != NULL){
                delete[] deviceInterfaceDetail;
                deviceInterfaceDetail = NULL;
            }

            if(retval != FALSE) break; //устройство уже найдено

            deviceIndex++; //следующее устройство
        }       

        SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(deviceInfoHandle);
    }
    else ErrorMes(L"SetupDiGetClassDevs");

    return retval;
}

//таблица номеров для всех дисков
bool disk_IsUsed[30]={0};
STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER disk_number[30]={0};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");

    HANDLE hVol;    
    DWORD nbytes;
    WCHAR letter;
    WCHAR volume[100]={0};
    int i;
    STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER sdn={0};

    //заполняем таблицу номеров для дисков
    for(i=0;i<30;i++){      
        letter = 'A' + i;
        wsprintf(volume,L"\\\\.\\%c:",letter);              

        disk_IsUsed[i] = FALSE;
        hVol = CreateFile( volume,  0, 
               FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL,
               OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
        if(hVol == NULL || hVol == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){continue;} 

        BOOL ret = DeviceIoControl(hVol,                // handle to device
            IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER, // dwIoControlCode
            NULL,                            // lpInBuffer
            0,                               // nInBufferSize
            (LPVOID) &(disk_number[i]),           // output buffer
            (DWORD) sizeof(STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER),         // size of output buffer
            (LPDWORD) &nbytes,       // number of bytes returned
            NULL      // OVERLAPPED structure
        );
        CloseHandle(hVol);

        if(ret == FALSE){continue;}                 

        disk_IsUsed[i] = TRUE;      
    }       

    WCHAR match[1024]={0};

    GUID guid = { 0xF18A0E88, 0xC30C, 0x11D0, { 0x88, 0x15, 0x00, 0xA0, 0xC9, 0x06, 0xBE, 0xD8 } };    
    /*USB HUB Interface class GUID*/    

    HDEVINFO deviceInfoHandle = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&guid, 0, 0, DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE);

    if (deviceInfoHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        int deviceIndex = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA deviceInterface = { 0 };
            deviceInterface.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA);

            //получение всех USB-концентраторов
            if (SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(deviceInfoHandle, 0, &guid, deviceIndex, &deviceInterface))
            {
                DWORD cbRequired = 0;

                SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(deviceInfoHandle, &deviceInterface, 0, 0, &cbRequired, 0);
                if (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER == GetLastError())
                {
                    PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA deviceInterfaceDetail = 
                        (PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA)(new char[cbRequired]);
                    memset(deviceInterfaceDetail, 0, cbRequired);
                    deviceInterfaceDetail->cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA);

                    if (!SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(deviceInfoHandle, &deviceInterface, 
                        deviceInterfaceDetail, cbRequired, &cbRequired, 0))
                    {
                        delete[] deviceInterfaceDetail;
                        deviceIndex++;
                        continue;
                    }

                    // Initialize the structure before using it.
                    memset(deviceInterfaceDetail, 0, cbRequired);
                    deviceInterfaceDetail->cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA);

                    // Call the API a second time to retrieve the actual
                    // device path string.
                    BOOL status = SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(
                        deviceInfoHandle,  // Handle to device information set
                        &deviceInterface,     // Pointer to current node in devinfo set
                        deviceInterfaceDetail,   // Pointer to buffer to receive device path
                        cbRequired,   // Length of user-allocated buffer
                        &cbRequired,  // Pointer to arg to receive required buffer length
                        NULL);        // Not interested in additional data

                    BOOL res;                   

                    /*Открываем устройство для отправки IOCTL*/
                    HANDLE handle = CreateFile(deviceInterfaceDetail->DevicePath, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 
                        0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

                    if(handle!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {

                         DWORD bytes_read=0;
                         UINT ports = 0;
                         USB_NODE_INFORMATION nodeinfo;
                         USB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX coninfo={0};
                         const UINT BUFSIZE = 1000;
                         char buffer[BUFSIZE]={0};
                         USB_DESCRIPTOR_REQUEST* req = (USB_DESCRIPTOR_REQUEST*)&buffer;
                         USB_STRING_DESCRIPTOR* desc;

                         ZeroMemory(&nodeinfo,sizeof(nodeinfo));
                         nodeinfo.NodeType = UsbHub;                         

                        //получаем число портов на концентраторе                         
                        res=DeviceIoControl(handle,IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_INFORMATION  ,
                            &nodeinfo,sizeof(nodeinfo),&nodeinfo,sizeof(nodeinfo),&bytes_read,0);

                        if(res==FALSE)ErrorMes(L"DeviceIoControl"); 
                        else ports = (UINT)nodeinfo.u.HubInformation.HubDescriptor.bNumberOfPorts;

                        for(int j=1;j<=ports;j++){
                            ZeroMemory(&coninfo,sizeof(coninfo));
                            coninfo.ConnectionIndex=j;

                            //получаем инфу о порте
                            res=DeviceIoControl(handle,IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX ,
                            &coninfo,sizeof(coninfo),&coninfo,sizeof(coninfo),&bytes_read,0);
                            if(res==FALSE){ErrorMes(L"DeviceIoControl");continue;}

                            if(coninfo.ConnectionStatus==0) continue; //нет устройства

                            printf("\n- Hub %2d, Port %2d: USB v%x device\n",deviceIndex,
                                    j,(int)coninfo.DeviceDescriptor.bcdUSB);
                            printf("VID: %04X PID: %04X\n",(int)coninfo.DeviceDescriptor.idVendor
                                    ,(int)coninfo.DeviceDescriptor.idProduct); 

                            //формируем строку для поиска устройства
                            wsprintf(match,L"VID_%04X&PID_%04X",(UINT)coninfo.DeviceDescriptor.idVendor
                                    ,(UINT)coninfo.DeviceDescriptor.idProduct);

                            /*Serial number*/
                            ZeroMemory(buffer,BUFSIZE);                         
                            req->ConnectionIndex=j;
                            req->SetupPacket.wValue = (USB_STRING_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE << 8) + coninfo.DeviceDescriptor.iSerialNumber;
                            req->SetupPacket.wLength = BUFSIZE - sizeof(USB_DESCRIPTOR_REQUEST);
                            req->SetupPacket.wIndex = 0x409; //US English
                            res=DeviceIoControl(handle,IOCTL_USB_GET_DESCRIPTOR_FROM_NODE_CONNECTION ,
                                &buffer,sizeof(buffer),&buffer,sizeof(buffer),&bytes_read,0);
                            if(res==FALSE){ErrorMes(L"DeviceIoControl");continue;}
                            desc = (USB_STRING_DESCRIPTOR*)(&req->Data[0]);
                            wprintf(L"Serial: %s\n",desc->bString);

                            /*Vendor*/
                            ZeroMemory(buffer,BUFSIZE);                         
                            req->ConnectionIndex=j;
                            req->SetupPacket.wValue = (USB_STRING_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE << 8) + coninfo.DeviceDescriptor.iManufacturer;
                            req->SetupPacket.wLength = BUFSIZE - sizeof(USB_DESCRIPTOR_REQUEST);
                            req->SetupPacket.wIndex = 0x409; //US English
                            res=DeviceIoControl(handle,IOCTL_USB_GET_DESCRIPTOR_FROM_NODE_CONNECTION ,
                                &buffer,sizeof(buffer),&buffer,sizeof(buffer),&bytes_read,0);
                            if(res==FALSE){ErrorMes(L"DeviceIoControl");continue;}
                            desc = (USB_STRING_DESCRIPTOR*)(&req->Data[0]);
                            wprintf(L"Vendor: %s\n",desc->bString);

                            /*Product*/
                            ZeroMemory(buffer,BUFSIZE);                         
                            req->ConnectionIndex=j;
                            req->SetupPacket.wValue = (USB_STRING_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE << 8) + coninfo.DeviceDescriptor.iProduct;
                            req->SetupPacket.wLength = BUFSIZE - sizeof(USB_DESCRIPTOR_REQUEST);
                            req->SetupPacket.wIndex = 0x409; //US English
                            res=DeviceIoControl(handle,IOCTL_USB_GET_DESCRIPTOR_FROM_NODE_CONNECTION ,
                                &buffer,sizeof(buffer),&buffer,sizeof(buffer),&bytes_read,0);
                            if(res==FALSE){ErrorMes(L"DeviceIoControl");continue;}
                            desc = (USB_STRING_DESCRIPTOR*)(&req->Data[0]);
                            wprintf(L"Product: %s\n",desc->bString);       

                            /*Disk letter*/
                            res = FindDiskNumber(match,&sdn);
                            if(res != FALSE) {
                                for(i=0;i<30;i++)   
                                if( disk_IsUsed[i] !=FALSE 
                                    && disk_number[i].DeviceNumber == sdn.DeviceNumber
                                    && disk_number[i].DeviceType == sdn.DeviceType)
                                {
                                    letter = 'A' + i;
                                    printf("Disk letter: %c\n",letter);
                                }
                            }
                            else printf("Disk letter not found\n");

                        }

                        CloseHandle(handle);
                    }else{
                        ErrorMes(L"CreateFile");//failed to open device
                    }//endif


                    delete[] deviceInterfaceDetail;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }

            ++deviceIndex;
        }


        SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(deviceInfoHandle);
    }
    else ErrorMes(L"SetupDiGetClassDevs");

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Должно вывести подобный результат:

> ‐ Hub  3, Port  1: USB v200 device
>   VID: 8564 PID: 1000
>   Serial: 5B94314A
>   Vendor: JetFlash
>   Product: Mass Storage Device
>   Disk letter: G
>
> ‐ Hub  3, Port  4: USB v110 device
>   VID: 09DA PID: 000A
>   Serial: ?
>   Vendor: A4Tech
>   Product: USB Mouse
>   Disk letter not found
>
> ‐ Hub  3, Port  6: USB v110 device
>   VID: 046E PID: 5505
>   Serial: ?
>   Vendor: BTC
>   Product: USB Multimedia Keyboard
>   Disk letter not found
>
> ‐ Hub  3, Port 10: USB v200 device
>   VID: 04E8 PID: 689E
>   Serial: 1234567890ABCDEF
>   Vendor: SAMSUNG Electronics Co., Ltd.
>   Product: Samsung Android USB Device
>   Disk letter: H

Comment: У меня не выводит этот код подключённые устройства . Вывод: „«п Їа®¤®«¦Ґ­Ёп ­ ¦¬ЁвҐ «оЎго Є« ўЁиг . . .  "путем к устройству" я понимаю диск  D://,I:// , который определила система когда устройство было вставленно

Comment: Кроме этого многочисленные предупреждения: missing initializer for member ,ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to и одна ошибка :undefined reference to `_imp__CLSIDFromString@8'   ...... Если не закомментировать строчку :HRESULT hr = CLSIDFromString(L"{F18A0E88-C30C-11D0-8815-00A0C906BED8}", (LPCLSID)&guid);

Comment: @IvanTriumphov Это примерный код, он заточен под Visual C++. Да, есть отступления от стандарта. Строку с вызовом CLSIDFromString нельзя закомментировать, нужно добавить в параметры компоновщика библиотеку импорта для Ole32.dll. Ну, либо переписать объявление GUID без нее, как инициализацию структуры.

Comment: MSDN.WhiteKnight  у меня две ошибки : 'DEVPKEY_Device_Parent' was not declared in this scope
                      &DEVPKEY_Device_Parent,&dpt,(PBYTE)buffer,1000,NULL,0); и ошибка: 'SetupDiGetDeviceProperty' was not declared in this scope
                      &DEVPKEY_Device_Parent,&dpt,(PBYTE)buffer,1000,NULL,0);
                                                                           ^
                       ^

Comment: Ещё библиотеки какой то не хватает ?

Comment: @IvanTriumphov Вы случаем не собираете проект с указанием в параметрах Windows XP в качестве целевой версии ОС? Потому что функция SetupDiGetDeviceProperty появилась только начиная с висты. Макросы WINVER или _WIN32_WINNT у вас как-то определены?

Comment: Я извиняюсь за свое лузерство, как указать в Qt Creator целевую систему версии ОС ? И как определить макросы WINVER или _WIN32_WINNT

Comment: @IvanTriumphov Например, прописать перед включением windows.h строку `#define WINVER 0x0600` (соответствует Vista). А определить, какое значение установлено сейчас, можно как обычную переменную `printf("0x%x\n",WINVER);`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78818/discussion-between-ivan-triumphov-and-msdn-whiteknight).