# Некорректный серийный номер USB накопителя

Tags: c++, winapi

Не могу решить следующую проблему: при получении серийного номера средствами Winapi или WMI получаю следующую последовательность для некоторых устройств: `12345678123456781234567812345678`.

При этом серийный номер корректно отображается в ветке реестра

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB`

и в вызове команды

`udevadm info -q all -n /dev/sda8 | grep SERIAL`.

Пробовал различные способы, на данным момент код такой:

```
std::string getSerialNumber(HANDLE h)
{
    std::string result;
    static STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY spq = { StorageDeviceProperty, PropertyStandardQuery };
    union {
        PVOID buf;
        PSTR psz;
        PSTORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR psdd;
    };
    ULONG size = sizeof(STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR) + 0x100;
    ULONG dwError;
    do
    {
        dwError = ERROR_NO_SYSTEM_RESOURCES;
        if (buf = LocalAlloc(0, size))
        {
            if (DeviceIoControl(h, IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY, &spq, sizeof(spq), buf, size, 0, 0))
            {
                if (psdd->Version >= sizeof(STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR))
                {
                    if (psdd->Size > size)
                    {
                        size = psdd->Size;
                        dwError = ERROR_MORE_DATA;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (psdd->SerialNumberOffset)
                        {
                            result = psz + psdd->SerialNumberOffset;
                            dwError = NOERROR;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            LocalFree(buf);
        }
    } while (dwError == ERROR_MORE_DATA);
    return result;
}
```

Проблема также наблюдается при определении серийного номера SSD.

Comment: Речь о серийном номере дискового раздела или серийном номере USB-устройства? Вот здесь есть код для получения второго: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/835083/Как-получить-информацию-о-подключенном-устройстве/839741#839741

Comment: речь о серийном номере устройства, зашитого производителем

Comment: А что именно вы передаете в функцию параметром HANDLE h?

Comment: `HANDLE h = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0", 0, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);`

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, это решило проблему

Comment: Видимо, IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY не работает для USB-накопителей. У вас сработало решение по ссылке? (ОК, понял, что сработало)