# Перечисление USB-устройств

Tags: c++, linux, windows, usb, libusb

Понадобилось написать программу, выполняющую функцию подобно утилите Linux - `lsusb`. Вывод должен быть похож на:

[image: Вывод команды lsusb]

Я решил использовать библиотеку `libusb-1.0`. У меня получился вот такой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
#include "libusb.h"

using namespace std;

void print_device(libusb_device *dev) {
  struct libusb_device_descriptor desc;
  libusb_device_handle *handle = NULL;
  unsigned char str[256] = {0};

  if (libusb_get_device_descriptor(dev, &desc) < 0) {
    cout << "failed to get device descriptor" << endl;
    return;
  }

  cout << "Bus " << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(3) << hex << +libusb_get_bus_number(dev) << " "
       << "Device " << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(3) << hex << +libusb_get_device_address(dev) << ": "
       << "ID " << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(4) << hex << desc.idVendor << ":"
       << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(4) << hex << desc.idProduct;

  if (libusb_open(dev, &handle) == LIBUSB_SUCCESS) {
    if (desc.iProduct) {
      if (libusb_get_string_descriptor_ascii(handle, desc.iProduct, str, sizeof(str)) > 0) {
        string s(reinterpret_cast<char*>(str));
        cout << " " << s.substr(s.find_first_not_of(" \t"));
      }
    }
  } else cout << " -";
  cout << endl;
  if (handle) libusb_close(handle);
}

int main() {
  libusb_device **devs;
  ssize_t cnt;
  if (libusb_init(NULL) < 0) return 1;
  cnt = libusb_get_device_list(NULL, &devs);
  if (cnt < 0) return 1;
  for (int i = 0; devs[i]; i++) print_device(devs[i]);
  libusb_free_device_list(devs, 1);
  libusb_exit(NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

Но сборка под Linux (Manjaro Linux) не выводит названия устройств. Получается просто вот так:

[image: вывод моей программы под Linux]

Если произвожу сборку под Windows x64, то названия выводятся частично:

[image: вывод моей программы под Windows]

Для уточнения, Linuх - под виртуальной машиной, Windows на реальной. Поэтому список устройств отличается.

**Вопрос**

Я не правильно использую библиотеку `libusb` для вывода названий USB-устройств? Если "да", то как правильно?

**UPD**

Запуск моей проги под Линуксом, но под рутом - несколько исправил положение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы неправильно применяете std::string, удивительно, что ваша программа не бахает с сегфолтом.

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/835083/

Comment: gbg, а что неправильно и где, и как правильно?

Comment: MSDN.WhiteKnight, спасибо, почитаю.

Comment: `libusb_get_string_descriptor_ascii` возвращает строку, прошитую в само устройство, то что `lsusb -v` выводит в `iProduct`... а `lsusb` просто смотрит `idVendor` и `idProduct` в своей базе данных (`/usr/share/misc/usb.ids`, точное местоположение может отличаться).

Comment: @Majestio, а из неправильного — проcтая опечатка —  `sizeof(string)` для размера буфера засунул вместо `sizeof(str)`

Comment: @Fat-Zer , на счет sizeof, да - очепятка, спасибо!

Comment: @Fat-Zer, на счет базы - догадывался ... Есть GUI прога с похожей базой. Похоже ваш ответ - и есть ответ на эту мою тему. Еще раз спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка у вас вот тут:

```
if (libusb_get_string_descriptor_ascii(handle, desc.iProduct, str, sizeof(string)) > 0) {
        string s(reinterpret_cast<char*>(str));
```

`sizeof(string)` - это размер экземпляра класса `string`, ничего общего с размером буфера строки не имеет.

Как можно решить проблему (без костыля с буфером):

```
string str(2048); //сразу с хорошим запасом выделяем память
if(libusb_get_string_descriptor_ascii(handle, desc.iProduct, str.data(), str.size() > 0) 
{
    str.resize(strlen(str.c_str()); //обрезаем строку по '\0'
    str=str.substr(str.find_first_not_of(" \t")); 
}
```

Comment: Это была действительно ошибка, но это - очепятка, и я ее исправил. Спасибо. Ваш вариант - тоже вариант.

Comment: И кстати, там еще `str.data()` нужно будет кастовать к `unsigned char*`